# Why was my original answer to a question on the distinction between metaphysics and mysticism deleted?

Tags: discussion

I answered [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30548/what-is-the-distinction-between-mysticism-and-metaphysics) question on the differences between mysticism amd metaphysics was deleted three years ago by a mod without any acknowledgement to me that this had been done.

Why?

I only discovered it when a new answer brought it to the front page.

I would like an explanation.

Comment: Blèss you. 



Answer (score 1):

It was flagged as low quality due to false, unsubstantiated claims (especially on who called the Aristotelian texts "metaphysics" when).

Since the *standard* moderational procedure for that flag is deletion and the person who flagged argued well for it, one of our moderators followed the suggestion.

I agree that some kind of automatic (or manual) notice should accompany any deletion but that is not actually mandatory.

Comment: When I look at my answer, what I strikes me immediately as low-quality is the number of typos. But that not the indication of low quality but a rushed job. Given that the claim by the flagger doesn't stack up can I have my post reinstated? The flagger complained of "low quality, false claims (especially on who called the Aristotelian texts 'metaphysics' when)", after all, that story is repeated by both the SEP and Wikipedia? I know Wikipedia is often prone to lapses of judgement because of its open editor model but the SEP is edited professionally by a qualified body of scholars.

Comment: I down-voted your response by mistake before realising that you weren't advocating that my post was "low-quality" with "false claims" but merely repeating what the flagger had written.